# Does it have any problem to define same variable name on the multi modules in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, commonjs

I'm trying sublet big single source code to small modules.
I want to use same variable name on each jsfile. But them are required on mainjs file.

Does it makes any problem?

#### main.js

```
require('./module1');
require('./module2');
```

#### module1

```
let obj = new Something();
```

#### module2

```
let obj = new Something();
```

Comment: No, there's no problem. That's the whole point of having modules.

Comment: In your `main.js` you need to assign them to two unique variables.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts So Your mean is it has no problem when I use this variables on different modules?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each module is a separate entity and you can use same variables in different modules. But not same variables in a single module. 
By means of a separate entity is that stack of variables are maintained separately for each module when its complied.

Comment: If we import all these modules that share the same variable name into for example index.js, how would that play out?